# convert pixel x,y position on map to lat and long

Tags: javascript, jquery, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

My map takes up 100% width and height of the browser screen.. I have a draggable div that is super imposed over the map, I am am capturing this divs position using `offset()`; to get the pixel `top` and `left` values.

I am trying to convert these values to `latitude` and `longitude`... How could this be done?

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ -> Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert from pixels coordinates to map coordinates and vice-versa, is one of the main task of geographic libraries.

In this case you just need to use the method `toMap` of the `MapView` (assuming you are using 4.x library), this method takes a screen coordinate (where 0,0 is the top left corner of the map) and returns the correspondant map coordinate.

[ArcGIS JavaScript API latest - MapView toMap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#toMap)

In case you are using 3.y version, you need to use the method `toMap` but in this case of the `Map`.

[ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.32 - Map toMap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#tomap)

Comment: Thanks... "Convert from pixels coordinates to map coordinates and vice-versa, is one of the main task of geographic libraries." .. yeah one would think, lol

Comment: Glad it help you!